# Splitting a string at n-th character with different length

Tags: android, split

i am trying to split string. I am using

```
for (String part : getParts(RESPONSE_STRING, 3)) {
                        // System.out.println(" MY STRING " + part);
                        partlist.add(part);

                    }

 private static List<String> getParts(String string, int partitionSize) {
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
    int len = string.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += partitionSize) {
        parts.add(string.substring(i, Math.min(len, i + partitionSize)));
    }
    return parts;
}

MY input is 0130010010102255051
output : 013 001 001 010 225 505 1
```

but i want my output

```
 013 001 001 01 02 255 051
```

How do i achive this output ?  Any idea of how to get my characters ? Many Thanks

Comment: is the pattern always same?

Comment: What is the actual rule for how the string should be split?

Comment: As long as `i + partitionSize < len` you'll get the same "range": `[i, i + partitionSize]` for every iteration. Why would you expect some of the iterations to return a substring of size 3 and some of size 2 ?

Comment: yes pattern will be always same

Comment: @alfasin - i need to do so for updating database

Comment: dude, you defined `getParts(RESPONSE_STRING, 3)` and you're getting parts of 3. If you want parts of 2, 4 or anything else - modify your partitioning method!

Comment: @alfasin - some of the character defined values and some defines its ID

Comment: @alfasin - thats the problem. its giving me parts of three. now i need part of two from 10th character.

Comment: And then you need parts of 3 again from the 14th character ?

Comment: anyways thank you so much for quick responses. i solved this issue by using static function  String.substring(int start,int end) for now..